# Sorting the array that I have programmed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make an array of my recent Valorant Premier Matches.

The problem is, that I can't sort the array in any way, it seems to just sort itself and I don't know where.

My plan is to sort the array with the `pointsBefore` or `pointsAfter` value, so that the most recent match (with the highest value) is at the top while the first match is at the bottom (lowest value).

I hope you can help me!

```js
async function fetchMatchData(matchId) {
  const matchUrl = `https://api.henrikdev.xyz/valorant/v2/match/${matchId}`;
  const response = await fetch(matchUrl);
  const matchData = await response.json();
  return matchData.data;
}

async function fetchAndDisplayMatches() {
  const historyUrl = "https://api.henrikdev.xyz/valorant/v1/premier/70921669-f22e-4a59-9e26-f19664a1fa20/history";
  const response = await fetch(historyUrl);
  const historyData = await response.json();
  const leagueMatches = historyData.data.league_matches;

  // Sort the matches array based on points_before in descending order
  leagueMatches.sort((a, b) => b.points_before - a.points_before);

  const matchHistoryElement = document.getElementById("match-history");

  leagueMatches.forEach(async(match) => {
    const matchId = match.id;
    const matchData = await fetchMatchData(matchId);

    const redTeamName = matchData.teams.red.roster.name;
    const blueTeamName = matchData.teams.blue.roster.name;
    const isJstCarry = redTeamName === "JstCarry";
    const displayTeamName = isJstCarry ? blueTeamName : redTeamName;

    const redRoundsWon = matchData.teams.red.rounds_won;
    const redRoundsLost = matchData.teams.red.rounds_lost;
    const blueRoundsWon = matchData.teams.blue.rounds_won;
    const blueRoundsLost = matchData.teams.blue.rounds_lost;
    const roundsWon = isJstCarry ? redRoundsWon : blueRoundsWon;
    const roundsLost = isJstCarry ? redRoundsLost : blueRoundsLost;
    const matchScore = `${roundsWon} : ${roundsLost}`;

    const matchBox = document.createElement("div");
    matchBox.classList.add("match-box");

    if ((isJstCarry && redRoundsWon > redRoundsLost) || (!isJstCarry && blueRoundsWon > blueRoundsLost)) {
      const victoryDefeatElement = document.createElement("div");
      victoryDefeatElement.classList.add("victory-defeat");
      victoryDefeatElement.textContent = "VICTORY";
      matchBox.appendChild(victoryDefeatElement);
    } else {
      const victoryDefeatElement = document.createElement("div");
      victoryDefeatElement.classList.add("victory-defeat");
      victoryDefeatElement.textContent = "DEFEAT";
      matchBox.appendChild(victoryDefeatElement);
    }

    const jstCarryTeamNameElement = document.createElement("div");
    jstCarryTeamNameElement.classList.add("team-name", "left");
    jstCarryTeamNameElement.textContent = "JstCarry";

    const displayTeamNameElement = document.createElement("div");
    displayTeamNameElement.classList.add("team-name", "right");
    displayTeamNameElement.textContent = displayTeamName;

    const scoreElement = document.createElement("div");
    scoreElement.classList.add("score");
    scoreElement.textContent = matchScore;

    const pointsBefore = match.points_before; // Get the points_after value

    const pointsAfter = match.points_after; // Get the points_after value
    const pointsElement = document.createElement("div");
    pointsElement.classList.add("points");
    pointsElement.textContent = `${pointsBefore} ➜ ${pointsAfter} points`;




    matchBox.appendChild(jstCarryTeamNameElement);
    matchBox.appendChild(scoreElement);

    matchBox.appendChild(displayTeamNameElement);


    matchHistoryElement.appendChild(matchBox);
    scoreElement.appendChild(pointsElement); // Add the points element to the match box
  });
}

fetchAndDisplayMatches();
```

```css
body {
  min-width: 540px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.match-box {
  background-color: #1B1C1E;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.victory-defeat {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.2;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.team-name {
  text-align: left;
}

.team-name.left {
  flex: 1;
}

.team-name.right {
  text-align: right;
  flex: 1;
}

.score {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.points {
  position: flex;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Valorant Match History</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="match-history"></div>

</body>

</html>
````

Comment: Did you debug what is happening? `leagueMatches.sort((a, b) => { console.log(b.points_before, a.points_before, b.points_before - a.points_before); return b.points_before - a.points_before });`

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the code dump. We only need to see the code that's directly relevant to your question, which would be the array and your attempt to sort it.  Then explain what result you are expecting by showing us an example of input and expected output, versus what output you're actually receiving.

Comment: You're sorting correctly. The problem is that you're calling an async function in `leageMatches.forEach()`. Those AJAX calls won't necessarily respond in order, so your output will not be in sorted order.

Comment: Use `Promise.all()` to process the responses in the same order as the calls.

Comment: I'm sorry @devlincarnate it's the first time I'm using stack overflow and I just recently started coding! I hope I didn't annoy you too much.

Comment: I hope it's not a dumb question, but how would I use Promise.all() in my example? :) @Barmar

Comment: I'm not annoyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not processing the results in sorted order, because you're calling an async function in the `forEach()` loop.

Make an array of all the promises returned by `fetchMatchData(matchId)` and then use `Promise.all()` to process them in order.

```js
async function fetchMatchData(matchId) {
  const matchUrl = `https://api.henrikdev.xyz/valorant/v2/match/${matchId}`;
  const response = await fetch(matchUrl);
  const matchData = await response.json();
  return matchData.data;
}

async function fetchAndDisplayMatches() {
  const historyUrl = "https://api.henrikdev.xyz/valorant/v1/premier/70921669-f22e-4a59-9e26-f19664a1fa20/history";
  const response = await fetch(historyUrl);
  const historyData = await response.json();
  const leagueMatches = historyData.data.league_matches;

  // Sort the matches array based on points_before in descending order
  leagueMatches.sort((a, b) => b.points_before - a.points_before);

  const matchHistoryElement = document.getElementById("match-history");

  const resultPromises = leagueMatches.map(match => fetchMatchData(match.id));
  (await Promise.all(resultPromises)).forEach((matchData, i) => {

    let match = leagueMatches[i];
    const redTeamName = matchData.teams.red.roster.name;
    const blueTeamName = matchData.teams.blue.roster.name;
    const isJstCarry = redTeamName === "JstCarry";
    const displayTeamName = isJstCarry ? blueTeamName : redTeamName;

    const redRoundsWon = matchData.teams.red.rounds_won;
    const redRoundsLost = matchData.teams.red.rounds_lost;
    const blueRoundsWon = matchData.teams.blue.rounds_won;
    const blueRoundsLost = matchData.teams.blue.rounds_lost;
    const roundsWon = isJstCarry ? redRoundsWon : blueRoundsWon;
    const roundsLost = isJstCarry ? redRoundsLost : blueRoundsLost;
    const matchScore = `${roundsWon} : ${roundsLost}`;

    const matchBox = document.createElement("div");
    matchBox.classList.add("match-box");

    if ((isJstCarry && redRoundsWon > redRoundsLost) || (!isJstCarry && blueRoundsWon > blueRoundsLost)) {
      const victoryDefeatElement = document.createElement("div");
      victoryDefeatElement.classList.add("victory-defeat");
      victoryDefeatElement.textContent = "VICTORY";
      matchBox.appendChild(victoryDefeatElement);
    } else {
      const victoryDefeatElement = document.createElement("div");
      victoryDefeatElement.classList.add("victory-defeat");
      victoryDefeatElement.textContent = "DEFEAT";
      matchBox.appendChild(victoryDefeatElement);
    }

    const jstCarryTeamNameElement = document.createElement("div");
    jstCarryTeamNameElement.classList.add("team-name", "left");
    jstCarryTeamNameElement.textContent = "JstCarry";

    const displayTeamNameElement = document.createElement("div");
    displayTeamNameElement.classList.add("team-name", "right");
    displayTeamNameElement.textContent = displayTeamName;

    const scoreElement = document.createElement("div");
    scoreElement.classList.add("score");
    scoreElement.textContent = matchScore;

    const pointsBefore = match.points_before; // Get the points_after value

    const pointsAfter = match.points_after; // Get the points_after value
    const pointsElement = document.createElement("div");
    pointsElement.classList.add("points");
    pointsElement.textContent = `${pointsBefore} ➜ ${pointsAfter} points`;

    matchBox.appendChild(jstCarryTeamNameElement);
    matchBox.appendChild(scoreElement);

    matchBox.appendChild(displayTeamNameElement);

    matchHistoryElement.appendChild(matchBox);
    scoreElement.appendChild(pointsElement); // Add the points element to the match box
  });
}

fetchAndDisplayMatches();
```

```css
body {
  min-width: 540px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.match-box {
  background-color: #1B1C1E;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.victory-defeat {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.2;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.team-name {
  text-align: left;
}

.team-name.left {
  flex: 1;
}

.team-name.right {
  text-align: right;
  flex: 1;
}

.score {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.points {
  position: flex;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Valorant Match History</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="match-history"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Aaaah I think I get it now. Thanks so much for your help! :) 

Have a great rest of the day! :)

Comment: @JstDave if this solves your problem don't forget to accept the answer (the checkbox) and upvote (the arrow up, if you have the permission) to reward the post author, that's how stackoverflow works

Comment: You could upvote the question to welcome the OP on stackoverflow